# HTML/Javascript/Jquery listview?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, listview

I've being working with a lot of WPF, and I used a lot of listviews to convey information. I wanted to create something like a detailed listview.

An example of what I'm looking for is the "listview" type interface on Facebook's newsfeed, or even Stack Overflow's question browsing list.

The data will come from an XML document. So far my solution was to use divs within divs, but unfortunately it ended up being very messy. I also tried making them with tables and then hiding the table borders (which worked to an extent) but I'm sure there must be a better way! I also heard using tables is not a very good way to do it.

I'm not even sure if the word "Listview" is the right term to describe what I'm trying to talk about. If there's a different term can you please also answer that so that I can search for that on Google too (because I've only been searching for Listview's in HTML/Javascript).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try listview plugins with ExtJs or Jquery.

Here's the listView example / doc from Jquery mobile 
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

**Listview** would be the term to identify the structure. The best possible way to implement it would be to use an un-ordered list ex: 



 and style it with CSS. Its simple and not too messy.